# Check Netframework remotely PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, remote-access, .net-framework

TLDR; Trying to check netframework version remotely.

Helpful info:

running win 7 home on all pcs

have network set to public (why I tried -SkipNetworkProfileCheck)

all windows firewalls should be off

main pc running code from has PS ver5

All other PSv2

I've ran my script, got that error, then ran the Winrm code but it doesn't seem to help.
I've looked into self made security certs but  I'm unsure if I need to go that route.

Error I'm getting:

```
[172.32.5.1] Connecting to remote server 172.32.5.1 failed with the following error message : The 
client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the 
destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS- 
Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the 
WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM 
service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (172.32.5.1:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Code i run:

```
# Read all the computers from the file
$computers = get-content C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DavidsStuff\ips.txt

# Perform an operation for each row in the file
foreach ($strComputer in $computers) {

$Username = 'Administrator'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass

Write-Host -Fore Green “Enabling RemoteRegistry service”
sc.exe \\$strComputer config remoteregistry start= auto

$scriptblockToExecute = {
Write-Host "IP: $strComputer"
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
}

Invoke-command -ComputerName $strComputer -Credential $Cred -Scriptblock $scriptblockToExecute
}
```

Winrm Code:

```
$computers = get-content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DavidsStuff\ips.txt"
foreach ($strComputer in $computers) {
psexec \\$strComputer -u Administrator -p password 
Set-WSManQuickConfig -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have PSRemoting in workgroup mode setup at all or properly.

• Enable PowerShell Remoting on a standalone (workgroup) computer
https://4sysops.com/archives/enable-powershell-remoting-on-a-standalone-workgroup-computer

• PowerShell remoting between two workgroup machines
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/24/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines

• Powershell Ps Remoting Between Standalone Workgroup Computers
http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/active-directory/powershell-ps-remoting-between-standalone-workgroup-computers

• PowerShell remoting between two workgroup machines
https://posh2scripting.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/powershell-remoting-between-two-workgroup-machines

• Enabling remote Powershell on workgroup computers
https://infrahouse.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/enabling-remote-powershell-on-workgroup-computers

• WinRM Security - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/winrmsecurity

• How to setup WinRM in a WorkGroup Non Domain Environment
https://www.paulligocki.com/how-to-setup-winrm-in-a-workgroup-non-domain-environment

• Tip: Work Remotely with Windows PowerShell without using Remoting or WinRM
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699046.aspx

```
Some cmdlets have a –ComputerName parameter that lets you work with a remote 
computer without using Windows PowerShell remoting. This means you can use 
the cmdlet on any computer that is running Windows PowerShell, even if the 
computer is not configured for Windows PowerShell remoting. These cmdlets 
include the following:

• Get-WinEvent
• Get-Counter
• Get-EventLog
• Clear-EventLog
• Write-EventLog
• Limit-EventLog
• Show-EventLog
• New-EventLog
• Remove-EventLog
• Get-WmiObject
• Get-Process
• Get-Service
• Set-Service
• Get-HotFix
• Restart-Computer
• Stop-Computer
• Add-Computer
• Remove-Computer
• Rename-Computer
• Reset-ComputerMachinePassword
```